# jquery FullCalendar issue removing event source when calendar is rendered

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I am using the jquery fullcalendar in a month view.  I have seen similar questions to mine but I can't seem to find one with the code that I am looking for.

The data brought back on the original rendering works fine.  I works when I use the next and prev buttons. I have added buttons that are handled by a click event that add a new event source to show and hide certain events on the calendar. Once this event source is added and I click next or prev, both events sources are called and rendered on the calendar.  How do I get a hold of the new event source and remove it?

I am using FullCalendar v1.6.3

My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var sourceFullView = { url: '/ISCalendar/GetRequestEvents/' };
   var sourceEvents = $.fullCalendar.events(source); // the reference
   var CalLoading = true;

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
           // left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },           
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: false,            
        events: sourceFullView,
        timeFormat: '',
        viewRender: function (view, element) {

            if (!CalLoading) {                    
                    console.log(events);
                    console.log(sourceFullView);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource',                     sourceEvents);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceFullView);                        
            }
        }
    });

    CalLoading = false;
});
```

// show or hide calendar objects

```
$(":button").click(function () {

    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-ok-circle icon-default-on').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove-circle icon-default-off');
    var id = '';
    var id = this.id;

    console.log('id = ' + id);

    if (id == 'announcements') {           
        if ($('.Announcement').is(":visible")) {
            $('#Announcement').val(1);
        } else {
            $('#Announcement').val(0);
        }
    }

    if (id == 'pending') {            
        if ($('.pending').is(":visible")) {
            $('.pending').hide();
            console.log('pending hide');
        }
        else {
            $('.pending').show();
            console.log('pending show');
        }
    }

    if (id == 'telecommute') {           
        if ($('.Telecommute').is(":visible")) {
            $('#Telecommute').val(6);
        } else {
            $('#Telecommute').val(0);
        }
    }

    if (id == 'my-next-button') {

        return false;
    }

    if (id == 'my-prev-button') {
        return false;
    }

    if (id == 'OnCall') {
        if ($('.OnCall').is(":visible")) {
            $('#ITOnCall').val(7);
        } else {
            $('#ITOnCall').val(0);
        }
    }

    if (id == 'approved') {
        if ($('.TimeOff').is(":visible")) {
            $('#Approved').val(3);
        } else {
            $('#Approved').val(0);
        }
    }

    var data = {
        'requestTypeAnnouncement': $('#Announcement').val(),
        'requestTypePending': $('#Pending').val(),
        'requestTypeApproved': $('#Approved').val(),
        'requestTypeTelecommute': $("#Telecommute").val(),
        'requestTypeItOnCall': $('#ITOnCall').val(),
    };

   var events = {
        url: '/ISCalendar/GetEventsFiltered',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data          
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);

    console.log('Announcement= ' + $('#Announcement').val());
    console.log('telecommute = ' + $('#Telecommute').val());
    console.log('itoncall    = ' + $('#ITOnCall').val());
    console.log('Approved    = ' + $('#Approved').val());        
});
```

Comment: Is `// show or hide calendar objects $(":button").click(function () {` supposed to be 2 lines?  Is it supposed to be part of the 2nd code block?

Comment: Sorry yes it is part of the 2nd code block.